# Hierarchy layout for any graph?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, graph, hierarchy

do you know if it is possible to use the `hierarchy` layout in d3.js, when the JSON file has this structure below? That means, the links are also a part of the JSON? Currently i only use the `hierarchy` layout with a tree type JSON data, but i wish to use it for any kind of graph? Thanks so much!

```
"Nodes": [
    {
      "Id": "338",
      "Name": "TEST NODE ONE",
      "Url": "http://www.google.com"
    },
    {
      "Id": "340",
      "Name": "TEST NODE TWO",
      "Url": "http://www.yahoo.com"
    } ]

"links": [
    {
      "source": 0,
      "target": 0,
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": 0,
      "target": 1,
      "value": "0"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: someone can help?